# What events are registered on my page?

Tags: javascript, dom, onkeydown, onkeyup

My problem is that every time I press "esc" button on my site it refreshed the page to the base root (without me even requesting it to happen). I have no idea what causes that and which event of keyup/keydown is registered.

My question is:

**How can I see what events are currently registered on my site so I can track this issue?**

Comment: On your site? Can't you look at the code?

Comment: this is probably not a code I've inserted and I assume it is triggered from on of the plugins I'm using. my question is really conceptual about the way I can list all the listeners on a specific event (keyup/keydown/click) in my document

Answer (score 0):

Check [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/visual+event+2)

It enables you to see the events that are registered on various elements of your page.